# error C3074: an array can only be initialized with an initializer-list

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c++11, initialization-list

I am working on a petty (pretty) printer for PODs, STLs and Composite Types like Arrays. While doing so, I was also fiddling with Initialization Lists and came across the following declaration

```
std::vector<double[3]> arr{ { 10, 11, 12 }, { 20, 21, 22 } };
```

It seems both VC2013 and G++ 4.8 is not quite happy and issues a consistent error message which in either case is not quite helpful to me

**For VC++:** `error C3074: an array can only be initialized with an initialize-list`

**For G++ 4.8:** `error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initialize`

So either Initialization lists cannot be used here or my syntax is quite not right?

On a similar front, the following syntax seems to be valid

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>  arr{ { 10, 11, 12 }, { 20, 21, 22 } };
```

What is the possible problem with my initialization list?

- **Note** I understand I should use `std::array` instead of C type arrays but I am just experimenting.
- **Note** If you wan't to play around with this, here is an [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/e.js/5uOFDq) version
- **Note** Also, it would be quite beneficial if you can refer me back to the standard.

Comment: Might it be one of those cases where you need an extra pair of curly braces `arr{{{ 10, 11,12}, {20, 21,22}}}`?

Comment: @LevLandau: No, this doesn't solves the problem.

Comment: In my experience with VC2010, it does not like multiple levels of curly braces in initializers. Try removing all but the outermost level of braces. That has worked for me, although I do not recall having used it with a templates class.

Comment: @Logicrat: Actually I am using VC2013 which is supposed to support Uniform Initialization Lists. I have cross checked with g++

Comment: Vectors require the type to be move-assignable and movable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the [current C++1y draft standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf).

From before Table 99:

> T
>   is
>   EmplaceConstructible
>   into
>   X
>   from
>   args
>   , for zero or more arguments
>   args
>   , means that the
>   following expression is well-formed:
>   allocator_traits::construct(m, p, args)

Table 100:

```
X(il);              |  Equivalent to      | X(il.begin(), il.end());
--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------
X(i, j);            |                     | Requires:
X a(i, j);          |                     | T shall be EmplaceConstructible
                                          | into X from *i.
```

So `std::vector<double[3]> v{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };` is valid iff `double[3]` is `EmplaceConstructible` from `{1,2,3}` as an element of an initializer list being passed to a `std::vector<double[3]>`.

There is a clause about forward iterators as well, but that is no problem (as `std::initialzier_list` iterators are forward iterators).

`std::vector<T>` takes an `std::initializer_list<T>` parameter.

So `std::initializer_list<double[3]>` is the candidate list.

First, `std::initializer_list<double[3]> x = {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}};` fails to compile in gcc.  But suppose that is a bug in gcc.

Second, `::new (nullptr) double[3](std::initializer_list<double>{1.0, 2.0, 3.0});` placement new, which `EmplaceConstructable` reduces to in the lack of a suitable `construct` override, fails to compile.

So `double[3]` is not `EmplaceConstruble` from a `std::initalizer_list<double>`  nor from a `double[3]` nor anything else (as the error occurs because I used a bracket, not because of what was in the brackets, in the placement new), unless the allocator does magic I am not aware of to avoid the placement new.

Thus your code violates the current draft standard, and probably C++11, and certainly C++03 (which had stricter requirements on containers).

Comment: May be I am missing something essential here, but analogously, why doesn't compiler complain if I code `std::vector<double[3]> arr; arr[0][0] = 1;`

Comment: @Abhijit Undefined behaviour; the compiler can do anything, including not complaining.

Comment: @AlanStokes: I don;t think so Yakk mentioned that its an UB, but then I would like to hear back from Yakk.

Comment: C++11 removed the global requirements on container template parameters, and now specifies requirements on the individual container functions that need those behaviors from their elements.

Comment: @Abhijit answer revised with the current draft standard instead of my memory of the C++03 standard.

Comment: More directly, I think, `std::allocator_traits::construct(m, p, args)` is not well-formed when `args` is an initializer list, since the function template parameter pack (`class... Args`) can't be deduced.

Comment: @aschepler `args...` is just `std::initializer_list<double[3]>` or `double[3]` or `std::initializer_list<double>` -- `args...` are actual arguments, not `{ blah }`, but what `{ blah }` has already been processed into.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in gcc and MSVC; clang compiles your code correctly.

Recent versions of gcc actually crash ("ice") the compiler:

> internal compiler error: tree check: expected class ‘type’, have ‘exceptional’ (error_mark) in useless_type_conversion_p, at tree-ssa.c:1189

The standard is reasonably clear; from **[dcl.init.list]**:

> 5 - An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated an array of `N` elements of type `E`, where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array. [...]

Adapting the example from that paragraph:

```
using E = double[3];
using X = std::vector<E>;
E __a[2] = {{10, 11, 12}, {20, 21, 22}};
X x(__a, __a+2);
```

This is a bit of a cheat, though; a closer translation would write `E __a[2] = {E{10, 11, 12}, E{20, 21, 22}};`, which is not valid. But it certainly *is* possible to copy-initialize an array `double[3]` from a braced-init-list: `E __a0 = {10, 11, 12};`

Comment: `This is a bug in gcc and MSVC`. Is this a documented bug? Also, I am quite not sure if [dcl.init.list] justifies the syntax. Moreover, I think, just because clang compiles, we can call it a bug (but its just what I think and I may be wrong :-) )

Comment: Hmm. If we wrap the inner braced-init-lists with `E` then we get the same error as gcc. But it certainly *is* possible to copy-initialize an array `double[3]` from a braced-init-list: `E __a0 = {10, 11, 12}`.

Comment: @Abhijit: Clang has bugs too. You can't just assume something is a bug in GCC simply because it compiles in Clang.

Comment: It isn't about constructing `double[3]` from a braced initializer list (although that is one step), you also need emplace constructible from `double[3]`.  And I don't think it is.

Comment: `double[3]` can't even legally be a container's `value_type` because it is not even `Erasable`. The specification results in a pseudo-destructor call, which isn't well-formed since pseudo-destructor calls are allowed for scalar types only.